# Recording of conversation

Tags: recording

In Finland, is it illegal to record a conversation in the working place without the agreement for all people speaking?

I mean, two people are having a conversation in the office and one of them is recording the conversation. The other person does not know anything about it. Is this illegal or legal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on who is doing the recording. [Chapter 24](http://www.finlex.fi/en/laki/kaannokset/1889/en18890039.pdf) of the penal code governs privacy and Section 5 therein outlaws eavesdropping, which includes third-party recording:

> (1) A person who unlawfully listens to or records with a technical
> device
>
> (1)a discussion, talk or other sounds of private life, where these are not in tended  for  his  or  her  knowledge,  and  which  occur
> or  arise  in  domestic premises or
>
> (2) in secret in other than in domestic premises, talk that is not intended to his  or  her  knowledge  or  to  the  knowledge  of  third
> parties  in  general, where  the  circumstances  are  such  that  the
> speaker  has  no  reason  to believe that a third party is listening
>
> shall be sentenced for  eavesdropping to a fine or to imprisonment for
> at most one year.

Otherwise, there is no requirement for all-party consent.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer. OK, I see. So, there is no legally excused offending if someone that you discuss with, records you **without** your agreement?

Comment: It's permitted to record a conversation that you're party to, and there is no requirement to inform other parties. There could be other specific restrictions such as laws against disseminating certain types of private information, also covered in that chapter.

Comment: I see. Thnx for the clarification!